# Computer inconsistently boots

Tags: hard-drive, boot, memory, power-supply, cmos

So my problem is that I've built a tower out of older hardware to run DOS/DOS games on, it has 512MB of RAM, its using onboard VGA video output, one 5200RPM IDE HDD, and one SATA DVD drive. Now as the title says it boots inconsistently, but not without pattern. I sometimes am able to continually boot/reboot it for days or longer with no problem, but other times it wont boot and I have to open it up to fix issues: which are also inconsistent. Sometimes popping out and reslotting the CMOS battery is enough, other times I have to unplug the power cable from the IDE drive, boot it, reboot it and it will be fine. Other times I have to unplug all hardware down to the RAM, including the CMOS battery and some onboard cables, boot it up and listen to the horrible no-RAM "beeeeeeeeeeep" for a few seconds, pull the power cable, replace everything and *then* it will reboot. Finally it ocassionally only requires that I move the various cables away from the CPU/cooling unit (at first I though maybe static interference) but then later after it properly booting a few times I rebooted, and tried to boot to a flash drive, and simply plugging it in while the machine was off was enough to stop it from booting.

BTW when I say "it doesnt boot" I mean the BIOS doesn't even initialize visuals, power management, or fan control. It powers on with a massive "VOOORRRRRFFFFFF" as the fan immediately kicks in at 4500RPM, never slows down, and the rest of the BIOS don't initialize. When this happens I often have to pull the power cable, as the interupt button refuses to hard-boot it while its like this.

Comment: Why are you bothering with this? Presuming you have a good-ish computer (Core 2 duo with 2-4GB RAM) [then get yourself a MS/DOS VM](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Install-DOS-622-Under-VirtualBox/)

Comment: I'm just going to [go out on a sturdy limb](https://lifebloodyoga.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/goats.jpg) here....old hardware == inconsistent hardware.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, A: because I have a substantially more powerful computer that could easily run DOSBox/VMs but I dont like the feel, there isn't the slightest bit of authenticity or nostalgia to it. I have all the same games I play on DOS on steam or newer game consoles, but I still vastly prefer the sense of nostalgia I get when I boot the computer straight to an MS-DOS prompt. B: because I have the hardware lying around and might as well repurpose it rather than leave it taking up more closet space.

Comment: @DrZoo That is actually quite a thin and plyable limb you've crawled out on. The notion that hardware is inherently inconsistent because its old is just absurd. I have a PowerMac G4 and PowerBook G3 that run fine, a PS2 that works great, a collection of floppy diskettes that have no read/write problems, old 20GB maxtor drives that are less dysfunctional than some of my modern SATA drives. *Broken* hardware=inconsistent hardware. *Old* hardware=less powerful hardware.

Comment: IMO as-is this is too broad, and not really clear as to what you're specifically asking us.  Step 1: Try a different, known-good power supply. Continue swapping hardware with know-good replacements until you find the culprit.

Comment: @AlisonE.E. yes I agree lol. I was searching for pictures and I found it too funny to pass up :) On the hardware fact, the main difference is your hardware is not acting strange. If it did start to act strange, would you go diving into it and try and fix it? Or would you move on and decide to get new hardware? Your description **it works great** asker's description **It powers on with a massive "VOOORRRRRFFFFFF" as the fan immediately kicks in at 4500RPM, never slows down, and the rest of the BIOS don't initialize** I don't quite see the absurdity given their hardware performance.

Comment: @DrZoo Yes, I would try to fix it rather than buying new hardware, and I had tried to extensively before asking this question. I've verified theres nothing wrong with the hardware itself, both the power supply and RAM work fine with other mobos, motherboard boots fine with nothing connected, and no-RAM beeps when no RAM is inserted, the CPU works fine in other mobos and the drives/cables also do. It seems to be something about the overall configuration rather than individual components, which is why I came here, to see if anyone else had thoughts as to what about the configuration was wrong.

Comment: When you moved the hardware to a new motherboard to verify that it worked fine, how long did you keep it on that motherboard? As you stated *I sometimes am able to continually boot/reboot it for days or longer with no problem*

Comment: @DrZoo, when I said days or longer I meant at the frequency which I reboot it (across say a three day span about 2-4 times), I tried rebooting it enough that the problem would have surfaced had it been the hardware. On a related note I feel like a moron, I had never thought to change out the CMOS battery with a new one to test if the battery was dead. Well after wapping out battery after battery from the pile in my battery drawer (so many batteries, dozens of batteries D: ) one of them finally booted fine a few times in a row. I guess the cells were alive but still drained in the first battery

Comment: This might sound silly but is the motherboard properly grounded? Have you had all of the voltages checked on the PSU and motherboard? I understand the feeling of nostalgia but I can honestly say that putting the VM in full screen should do the trick for you if you allow yourself to believe it's authenticity. If pulling out the CMOS battery is honestly fixing the issue then it sounds like a bad motherboard or bad battery.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it seems as though it was a bad battery. Again, I've been using DOSBox for years and just don't like it, it doesnt feel authentic in fullscreen either. Its not just games, its the little things that count: DOSBox doesn't contain things like the DEL or EDIT commands, a lot of non-game software doesn't work, it always display that youre mounting host dirs, you have to mount FDDs, theres no need to manage memory usage, you can't get stuck with midi bleeps if you don't use a sound card. Some consider these drawbacks, to me they're required or it isn't proper emulation, its simulation.

Comment: Well it sounds like you certainly know what you are doing so I certainly hope you can get your true nostalgia fix, good luck with your setup :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possible culprits in decreasing order of possibility:

1) Failing motherboard. Maybe a slightly leaky capacitor? Or even a loose contact?

2) Failing power supply. Causes unexplained erratic behavior.

3) Failing RAM. Do a memtest to confirm this.

I had the exact same problem, though mine usually resolved after powering everything down for a few hours. The problem was (believe it or not) a thinly cracked motherboard.